# how to get percentage of elements which equal to string value

Tags: python, pandas

How can I get the percentage of by group (`name`) for `t_results` equals to "ok" ?

```
    name   t_result
0   aaa    ok   
1   aaa    err_1
2   bbb    err_1
3   bbb    ok
4   aaa    err_2
5   aaa    ok


name, percentage
aaa   0.5
bbb   0.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mean` of boolean mask, compared by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html), convert to `0, 1` by [`Series.view`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html) or [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) and aggregate by `df['name']` as `Series`:

```
df1 = (df['t_result'].eq('ok')
                     .view('i1') # .astype(int)
                     .groupby(df['name'])
                     .mean()
                     .reset_index(name='percentage'))
print (df1)
  name  percentage
0  aaa         0.5
1  bbb         0.5
```

Solution with new column and aggregate by column name `name`:

```
df1 = (df.assign(percentage = df['t_result'].eq('ok').view('i1'))
         .groupby('name', as_index=False)
         .mean())
```